Prove $\frac{a^3}{b}+\frac{b^3}{c}+\frac{c^3}{a}\ge ab+bc+ca \\\{a, b, c \in \mathbb{R^{+}}\}$
I've tried to use AM-GM, such as the 3rd AM-GM with $\frac{a^3}{b},\frac{b^3}{c},\frac{c^3}{a}$, but it doesn't work. Also tried to let $x=\frac{a}{b}, y=\frac{b}{c}, z=\frac{c}{a}$, tried Cauchy-Schwartz but hasn't worked. Factorising doesn't work either.

By Weighted AM-GM,
$\frac{5}{13}\left(\frac{a^3}{b}\right)+\frac{6}{13}\left(\frac{b^3}{c}\right)+\frac{2}{13}\left(\frac{c^3}{a}\right)\ge\left(\frac{a^3}{b}\right)^{\frac{5}{13}}\left(\frac{b^3}{c}\right)^{\frac{6}{13}}\left(\frac{c^3}{a}\right)^
{\frac{2}{13}}=ab$
$\frac{5}{13}\left(\frac{b^3}{c}\right)+\frac{6}{13}\left(\frac{c^3}{a}\right)+\frac{2}{13}\left(\frac{a^3}{b}\right)\ge\left(\frac{b^3}{c}\right)^{\frac{5}{13}}\left(\frac{c^3}{a}\right)^{\frac{6}{13}}\left(\frac{a^3}{b}\right)^
{\frac{2}{13}}=bc$
$\frac{5}{13}\left(\frac{c^3}{a}\right)+\frac{6}{13}\left(\frac{a^3}{b}\right)+\frac{2}{13}\left(\frac{b^3}{c}\right)\ge\left(\frac{c^3}{a}\right)^{\frac{5}{13}}\left(\frac{a^3}{b}\right)^{\frac{6}{13}}\left(\frac{b^3}{c}\right)^
{\frac{2}{13}}=ca$
Add all three inequalities to get,
$\frac{a^3}{b}+\frac{b^3}{c}+\frac{c^3}{a}\ge ab+bc+ca
$

how did you know to use 13?

We have by Titu's Lemma (Cauchy-Schwarz) we have
$$\frac{a^3}{b}+\frac{b^3}{c}+\frac{c^3}{a}=\frac{a^4}{ab}+\frac{b^4}{bc}+\frac{c^4}{ac}\ge\frac{\left( a^2+b^2+c^2 \right)^2}{ab+bc+ac}{\ge}ab+bc+ac$$
where the last inequality $a^2+b^2+c^2\ge ab+bc+ac$ is well known and can be proved by the means of Cauchy-Schwarz or AGM.
For a purely AGM solution, we just note that
$$5\frac{a^3}{b}+6\frac{b^3}{c}+2\frac{c^3}{a}\ge13\sqrt[13]{\frac{a^{15}}{b^5}\frac{b^{18}}{c^6}\frac{c^6}{a^2}}=13ab.$$
Now just cyclically sum to finish.

how did you know to use 13?

It was sufficient to find an inequality of form $x\frac{a^3}{b}+y\frac{b^3}{c}+z\frac{c^3}{a}\ge (x+y+z)ab$ so we need to find appropriate $x,y,z$. Since the power of $c$ must be zero $y=3z$. Since the power of $a$ and $b$ should be equal we have $3x-z=9z-x$ and thus $5z=2x$. Now any $x,y,z$ with this ratio works so for simplicity we choose $x=5, y=6, z=2$.

@Wafflefly21 Also informally known as "Method of unknown coefficients". You set it up and solve the system of linear equations. It tells you if a problem is naively AM-GM-able.

I used Re-arrangement Inequality rather than AM-GM 
BY Re-arrangement inequality statement
if $a_1 \geq b_1 \geq c_1$ 
and $a_2 \geq b_2 \geq c_2$ 
then any arrangement of the two inequalites $\geq (a_1)(c_2) + (b_1)(b_2) + (c_1)(a_2)$
Use internet to understand Re-arrangement inequality if you didnt it understand here
WLOG let $a \geq b \geq c$ 
Therefore $ a^{3} \geq b^{3} \geq c^{3}$ 
And $ \frac{1}{c} \geq \frac{1}{b} \geq \frac{1}{a}$ 
Also we already know $ a^{2} + b^{2} + c^{2} \geq ab + bc + ca$
And by Re-arrangement inequality:
Observe that $a^{2} + b^{2} + c^{2}$ is the smallest Arrangement of the merging of the two inequalites [inequality no.2 and no.3] given above and any other rearrangement of these inequalites will lead to a bigger value
Therefore
$ (a^{3})\frac{1}{b} +( b^{3})\frac{1}{c} + (c^{3})\frac{1}{a} \geq a^{2} + b^{2} + c^{2} \geq ab + bc + ca$
hence $ (a^{3})\frac{1}{b} +( b^{3})\frac{1}{c} + (c^{3})\frac{1}{a} \geq ab + bc + ca$
Hence proved
